# PayPal Plus provide payment method programmatically

Tags: api, paypal

I'm trying to integrate paypal plus wall without to show the select option iframe because I have a onestep checkout page.

I would like to pass to the PAYPAL.apps.PPP object a user selected payment method and on object creation do the checkout

so here is what I try but I can not preselect paypal payment methods

```
if(paypalWall) {
                //init paypal to make a preorder via PHP
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: $self.attr('action'),
                    data: $(form).serialize()

                }).done(function( data ) {
                    //I append but I do not show the ppp markup
                    $('body').append(data.html)

                    //here I try to pass the preselected payment method
                    paypalConfig.preselection = window.paypalOption

                    console.log(paypalConfig)
                    console.log(window.paypalOption);

                    var ppp = PAYPAL.apps.PPP(paypalConfig)
                    ppp.setPaymentMethod(paypalOption)

                    /* here should happen the magic: do the checkout */
                    //PAYPAL.apps.PPP.doCheckout()


            }).fail(function() {
                 alert( "Fehler!" );
            })
        }
```

I see inside `PAYPAL.apps.PPP` a `setPaymentMethod` but does not seems to work when I pass data to it. Can be used this method for the approach what I'm trying to achieve?